# error with type of string in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, string

A `print(user)` shows what I need, but the label wont take it. I don't really understand.
Can someone explain what's wrong ?

[Here is the printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Rt0u.png)

edited: here is the code :

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var etqRetards: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var etqBiens: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var etqSortie: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //on récupère l'utilisateur courant.
        let fm = FileManager.default
        let urlRepDocuments =  try! fm.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        let url = urlRepDocuments.appendingPathComponent("user.plist")
        if let dico = NSMutableDictionary.init(contentsOfFile: url.path){
            if dico["email"] != nil {
                let user = dico["email"] as! String
            }
        }
        etqBiens.text = user
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func btnLocataires(_ sender: Any) {
    }
    @IBAction func btnBatiments(_ sender: Any) {
    }
    @IBAction func btnOutils(_ sender: Any) {
    }


}
```

Comment: Please include your code **as text** here.

Comment: I have edited with the code

Comment: `user` is a let constant that is only accessible inside of the block where you defined it.  Make it a var at the start of `viewDidLoad()` `var user = ""`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the part where your code don't work anymore:

```
1: if let dico = NSMutableDictionary.init(contentsOfFile: url.path){
2:     if dico["email"] != nil {
3:        let user = dico["email"] as! String
4:    }
5: }
5: etqBiens.text = user
```

`user`will only be accessible on `row 3`, since it´s declared within that `if-statement`. What you need to do is to declare `user` globally so that you can access it and also declare it as a `var` to be able to change the value.

Do it like this instead:

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var etqRetards: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var etqBiens: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var etqSortie: UILabel!

    var user = "" // declare user here

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //on récupère l'utilisateur courant.
        let fm = FileManager.default
        let urlRepDocuments =  try! fm.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        let url = urlRepDocuments.appendingPathComponent("user.plist")
        if let dico = NSMutableDictionary.init(contentsOfFile: url.path){
            if dico["email"] != nil {
                user = dico["email"] as! String
            }
        }
        etqBiens.text = user
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func btnLocataires(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    @IBAction func btnBatiments(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    @IBAction func btnOutils(_ sender: Any) {
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean, to start off, user is not defined in the scope of the statement etqBiens.text...
If you want to copy the description of the user as a string, you can do so by saying user.description but I don't know how exactly that might be useful in the long run ¯\_(ツ)_/¯